# turning turtlebot a set number of degrees

Tags: c++, turtlebot, quaternion, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a way to turn my robot a certain angle in a cpp node. I have read through these questions:

http://answers.ros.org/question/12557/how-to-make-the-turtlebot-rotate-in-place-a-set-of/

The above made sense, so then I looked for a way to acquire the heading of the robot,

http://answers.ros.org/question/30926/getting-turtlebot-heading/

The user in the above question can already get their robot's quaternion data and I cannot making the answer not very helpful. Could someone explain an efficient way to acquire the robot's quaternion data and explain how the answer in the 2nd link works?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39549/turning-turtlebot-a-set-number-of-degrees/) by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 600 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arminf82](https://answers.ros.org/users/45412/arminf82/) on 2019-09-28**:
I think this could help.

http://www.theconstructsim.com/ros-qa-135-how-to-rotate-a-robot-to-a-desired-heading-using-feedback-from-odometry/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have a turtlebot, but some node should be publishing `nav_msgs/Odometry`, probably as an `/odom` or `/odom_combined` topic.

The `orientation` field in that message contains a quaternion indicating your robot's 3-dimensional orientation. Converting that to a yaw angle should give your 2-dimensional heading, if that is what you want.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on 2012-07-24**:
ahhhh of course, I feel really dumb, thank you.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-24**:
Don't feel bad. There is a lot going on in a full-sized ROS system.

**Comment by [Sanat](https://answers.ros.org/users/40275/sanat/) on 2019-03-05**:
I am even dumber, can figure out given these hints. Would be great to have some codes from you guys.